# Iterate through list in Pandas dataframe and summarized other column

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, dataframe

I have one, for me, tricky thing to do.

I have a df like this:

```
Side_a  childs                             column1
1001     NaN                                  3
1002     ['1001']                             5
1003     ['1001']                             3
1004     ['1001,'1003']                       6 
1005     ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004']     13
1006     ['1003', '1004']                     8
```

What I want is to create a new column that has summed column1 for all rows appeared in "childs" columns and own value from column1.

Column2 let's say should be:

```
side_a          childs                            column1  column2
1001       NaN                                      3         3
1002       ['1001']                                 5         8
1003       ['1001']                                 3         6
1004       ['1001','1003']                          6         12
1005       ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004']         13        30
1006       ['1003', '1004']                         8         17
```

To be honest, I didn't know where and how to start, so any hint is so welcomed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "a new column that has summed column1 for all rows appeared in "childs" and own value from column1". Do you want to calculate the sum for each group in `childs`? And why does values in `side_a` and `childs` change between input and output?

Comment: @user3471881 Hi, yes that's what I mean, the sum of each group plus the value of column1 in that row. For the difference between input and output, I have made a mistake, first put A,B,C then changed it to something that is more like a real data I have.

Comment: Then why does `column2` equal `8` when `side_a` is `1002` and `6`when `side_a` is `1003`?

Comment: Because 8 = 3 + 5, 3 is the value of column1 where side_a is 1001, and 5 is value of column1 for side_a=1002. Column2 should be a sum of column1 of that row and all elements in list in childs in that row. I assume you just forget own value from column1 for that row. But it would be ok even without own value, just sum of value from list, then it's easy to sum two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the rows belonging to the childs with `loc`. Finally you use `apply` to aggregate the columns with a custom function like:

```
def row_agg(row):
    column1 = row['column1']
    childs = df.loc[row['childs']]['column1'].sum() if isinstance(row['childs'],list) else 0
    return column1 + childs

df = df.set_index('Side_a')
df['column2'] = df.apply(row_agg, axis=1)

df

    childs  column1 column2
Side_a          
A   NaN         3   3
B   [A]         5   8
C   [A]         3   6
D   [A, C]      6   12
E   [A, B, C, D]13  30
F   [C, D]      8   17
```

Comment: I am getting an error: ("None of [['1315']] are in the [index]", 'occurred at index 1296') . Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Actually I'm fixing the answer, I used literal_eval but I don't think you need it, your childs column already has lists right?

Comment: You can check now, I considered the childs column to have lists.

Answer (score 1):

With `df` your above input dataframe, the following code produces the desired output

```
df.index = [str(x) for x in df['side_a']]
df['column2'] = df['column1'] + [sum(df['column1'].loc[df['childs'][i]]) if isinstance(df['childs'][i], list) else 0 for i in range(df.shape[0])]
```

It is not particularly elegant, and there surely is a more elegant way to do this, but it gets the job done

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: cannot use label indexing with a null key. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Can you confirm  that the code snippet works for `df = pd.DataFrame({'side_a': [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006], 'childs': [None, ['1001'], ['1001'], ['1001','1003'], ['1001', '1002', '1003', '1004'], ['1003', '1004']], 'column1': [3,5,3,6,13,8]})`?

Comment: I think I spotted the issue: I used Python's None for my test dataframe NaN. You can update the `if df['childs'][i] is not None` part of my second line to suit your type of Nan (be it np.nan or whatever you used)

Comment: Just an FYI, seeing another answer is accepted: I updated my code to deal with different types of NaNs, too. It should perform as expected on your dataframe now